# Get device (joystick) guid with windows multimedia (winmm.dll)

Tags: c#, unmanaged, multimedia, winmm

I try to implement interoperating with unmanaged code and c#.

I've decided to use winmm.dll for this.

There is need for get joystick unique guid and identify devise status (connected or not)

After some investigation i believe that founded out function that should to do it (**joyGetDevCapsA**). But there is not clear what value should be pass as **int id** parameter

```
public static class InputControllerInteroperator
    {
        private const string WINMM_NATIVE_LIBRARY = "winmm.dll";
        private const CallingConvention CALLING_CONVENTION = CallingConvention.StdCall;

        [DllImport(WINMM_NATIVE_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = CALLING_CONVENTION), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        public static extern int joyGetPosEx(int uJoyID, ref JOYINFOEX pji);

        [DllImport(WINMM_NATIVE_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = CALLING_CONVENTION), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        public static extern int joyGetPos(int uJoyID, ref JOYINFO pji);

        [DllImport(WINMM_NATIVE_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = CALLING_CONVENTION), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        public static extern int joyGetNumDevs();

        [DllImport(WINMM_NATIVE_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = CALLING_CONVENTION, EntryPoint = "joyGetDevCaps"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        public static extern int joyGetDevCapsA(int id, ref JOYCAPS lpCaps, int uSize);
    }
```

There is not lot information about winmm API for C# thought internet, so if someone have experience please share it.

**Q:** How can be detected attached or not joystick at current moment and get device unique Guid?

Comment: There is no guid, there is no connection state.  The specific joystick is identified with a simple uint.  0 is the first joystick, 1 is the second, etc.  Up to joyGetNumDevs.  This api is very old, goes back to Win3, do make sure your device still supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the **@Hans Passant** (https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) comments below question:

There is no guid, there is no connection state. The specific joystick is identified with a simple uint. 0 is the first joystick, 1 is the second, etc.

It works for me